# How to animate map circles in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a created a map, which shows arcs, with circles centered on the arcs destination. When the page is displayed, the circles are drawn, and the arc is drawn along its path.
What I wish to happen, is that the arc is drawn, as it is now, however, the circle should not appear until the arc has completed its path. The circle would "explode" and fade away.
Those familiar with the movie War Games would be familiar with this effect. https://media.giphy.com/media/yoJC2mtLhd0v19pJbW/giphy.gif
How to get the circle display when a 'bomb' touches down at the end of the arc. and then fade away?

```
map.bubbles(bombs, {
popupTemplate:function (geography, data) { 
        return ['<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' +  data.name + '</strong>',
        '<br/>Payload: ' +  data.yeild + ' kilotons',
        '<br/>Country: ' +  data.country + '',
        '<br/>Date: ' +  data.date + '',
        '</div>'].join('');
}
```

});
Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/dUbmmNcP6nnET537kO9w?p=preview

Comment: What you want to achieve is going to be difficult using a helper library like datamaps (it doesn't seem to allow you to hook transition end event). Have you thought about coding it yourself with straight `d3`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mark. I have taken your advice on board and decided to redo the map with v4. So with this in mind, I have started with a simple map and been reading on arcs with v4 in [the arcs docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_arc) but how do I apply this to the map? And, how to load the data from a json file? http://plnkr.co/edit/ttXZdjmZDaqtTNvhb6Qz?p=preview

Comment: Maybe I needs a separate post....